# Connected manifold and chart

Tags: general-topology

Let $M^n$ be a connected n-manifold (topological). Let $x,y\in M^n$. Show that there exists an open set $U$ containing both $x$ and $y$ and a homeomorphism $\phi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$.

Attempt:

As $M^n$ is connected, there exists a homeomorphism $h:M^n\rightarrow M^n$ such that $h(x)=y$. Let $(U,\phi)$ be a chart about $y$. So, $\phi:U\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is a homeomorphism. Consider  The homeomorphism $\phi\circ h|_{h^{-1}(U)}:h^{-1}(U)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$. How to complete the proof?

Comment: It seems that you know that connected manifolds are homogeneous. This *fact* does not help you, but I guess the *proof* will do.